# Python: pip looking in the wrong folder

Tags: python, pip

Short version of the question:  How can I get pip to install pyodbc in my Python 3.6 folder instead of seeing that it already exists in my 3.5 folder?

Because we have customers with various versions of Python, I have various versions on my computer.  Also, we have been using the ancient adodb provider via COM, and using the win32com package to talk to it.  Therefore, we have been using 32-bit versions of Python.

A new customer requires that we write to their Oracle database.  They installed an Oracle ODBC driver in their server.  However, it's a 64-bit ODBC driver, and when we run 32-bit Python, the driver will not be found.

A couple of years ago, I wrote a set of database wrapper classes based on adodb (and therefore on win32com) to meet our specific needs.  I recently learned about pyodbc, and rewrote those classes to use pyodbc and remove reliance on adodb and win32com.

For this customer, I would like to use my new pyodbc classes.  I tried to use pip to install pyodbc in my Python 3.6 installation, but it told me that the requirement is already satisfied because I have pyodbc in my Python 3.5 installation.  I can copy it into 3.6, but I'd like to be able to use pip.  What do I need to do?

Thank you.

Comment: check the pip documentation, specifically, the config file. http://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration

Comment: Many thanks for the link.  I found what I needed (and bookmarked it).